# Is there any fast way to get an <option> from a <select> by value, using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a <select>. Using JavaScript, I need to get a specific <option> from the list of options, and all I know is the value of the option.  The option may or may not be selected.

Here's the catch: there are thousands of options and I need to do this a few hundred times in a loop. Right now I loop through the "options" array and look for the option I want. This is too slow (in the sense that on my very fast machine the browser locked up until I killed it after a few minutes).

Is there any faster way to do this? I'll take browser-specific ways, but of course a DOM-standard way would be nice.

Comment: What kind of select requires the user to have thousand of options in it?
Perhaps if we had a little more detail we could figure out a more elegant way of implementing it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
// first, build a reverse lookup
var optCount      = mySelect.options.length;
var reverseLookup = {};
for (var i = 0; i < optCount; i++)
{
  var option = mySelect.options[i];
  if (!reverseLookup[option.value])
  {
    // use an array to account for multiple options with the same value
    reverseLookup[option.value] = [];
  }
  // store a reference to the DOM element
  reverseLookup[option.value].push(option);
}

// then, use it to find the option
var foundOptions = reverseLookup["Value that you are looking for"];
if (foundOptions && foundOptions.length)
{
  alert(foundOptions[0].id);
}
```

Comment: wouldn't you need to make a small framework to just handle the hundreds of reverse lookups all on the page?

Comment: I'm going to do it by having a named array that stores the reverse lookups by the id of the field being looked up on, because all my fields have ids (which are unique by definition).

Comment: I don't think you understood the code. Or I don't understand your objection. Can you clarify?

Comment: For those interested, you just helped me solve this bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=463598 (with the solving code attached to it). Thanks! :-)

Comment: Well, thank you for the flowers, as the German saying goes. ;-) Am I missing something essential in Nick Berardi's comment? Do you know what he means?

Comment: I think he means either that I need to do something to make it handle various different selects, or that I (fairly obviously) need to wrap the code in a function so that it becomes usable.

Comment: Good. I took that for granted, and you did the same, obviously.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not having thousands of options in your select.

Perhaps you could structure your data differently a select with thousands of entries to me seems wrong.

Perhaps your app requires this but it would not be typical usage of this element.

Comment: Administrators control how many options there are in the <select>, not me. I'm just trying extreme cases to make sure that they are still performant, because some of our users are crazy. :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is Tomalak's answer with a minor speed tweak. You see a while loop that iterates down is faster than a for loop that iterates up. (I'm lazy so I won't provide the link.)

```
var i = mySelect.options.length - 1;
var reverseLookup = {};
while ( i >= 0 )
{
  var option = mySelect.options[i];
  if (!reverseLookup[option.value])
  {
    // use an array to account for multiple options with the same value
    reverseLookup[option.value] = [];
  }
  // store a reference to the DOM element
  reverseLookup[option.value].push(option);
  i--;
}

// then, use it to find the option
var foundOptions = reverseLookup["Value that you are looking for"];
if (foundOptions && foundOptions.length)
{
  alert(foundOptions[0].id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

no there isn't, you are doing it really the best way possible.  The only other thing you can try for maybe a quicker look up is to give each of the options an ID tag so that you can look them up as a DOM object instead of looping through children of a DOM object.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through all the options once and put all items into an associative array. Then you can just look for `myOptions[valueImLookingFor]`.

I haven't tested this and can't guarantee it will be faster/better. But it should get rid of all those loops.

Depending on your setup and needs you could also generate a javascript array on the client side and put it in the markup instead of (or in addition to) the select.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to look at a framework/toolkit like [Dojo and its way of selecting DOM nodes](http://dojotoolkit.org/book/dojo-book-0-9/part-3-programmatic-dijit-and-dojo/selecting-dom-nodes-dojo-query).

The toolkit irons out alot of browser inconsistencies and allows you select and manipulate DOM nodes quickly and easily.

Comment: Yes but with this you have just traded parsing the DOM by your self in for an framework that parses the DOM in a more generalized way.  If the original posters code is tight and not wasting any unnecessary operations it will beat the frameworks every time.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it may be an indicator that "thousands" of items in a select probably isn't the best user experience. Maybe you should consider trying to limit your dropdowns to several that narrow the results as a user selects them.

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery something like this could be faster:

```
$("#idselect option[value='yourval']")
```

http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEquals#attributevalue

Comment: this is actually not faster at all it is just more compact.  because you have just replaced a "for" loop for jQuery doing a "for" loop because it still has to go through each option of a select element and look for a specific value.