# Dynamically set the value of select dropdown using query string paramater

Tags: javascript, html

To begin with, I'm new to Javascript.

I have a form with a select element with various options and I **do not have access to change the form**. There are no id's to the options, but just the values as shown in the code below.

```
    <form>
    <select class="country" name="country" id="countryid">
        <option value="usa" selected="selected">USA</option>
        <option value="canada">Canada</option>
        <option value="japan">Japan</option>
        <option value="china">China</option>
        </select>
    </form>
```

My goal is to populate the field in the above form automatically based on the url parameters. 
For example, www.example.com?country=china should populate China in the form field. The following is the javascript code:

```
<script>
var param1var = getQueryVariable("country");

function displayresult(){
    //document.getElementById(param1var).selected=true; //if there was id given in     the form field
        //cannot use document.getElementByValue(param1var).selected=true;
    //document.querySelectorAll('input[value=' + param1var + ']').selected=true; does not work
}

function getQueryVariable(variable) {
  var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
  var vars = query.split("&");
  for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");
    if (pair[0] == variable) {
      return pair[1];
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

1. I cannot use **document.getElementById**(param1var) because there is no id.
2. Javascript does not support **document.getElementByValue**(param1var).
3. **document.querySelectorAll** is not working.

Is there a way that I can reference the element using the option value?

Thanks!

Comment: You could just loop through the options until you find the value you’re looking for …

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490906/how-to-change-a-select-value-from-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any fast way to get an <option> from a <select> by value, using JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271892/is-there-any-fast-way-to-get-an-option-from-a-select-by-value-using-javascr)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do it this way by setting the value of the select element. Also note that value is case sensitive, plus make sure that the function `displayresult` runs on `onload` or after the element appeared in the html.

```
document.getElementById("countryid").value=param1var;
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8AKc/)**